# Парсер excel с помощью VBA на форму сайта

Tags: vba, excel, explorer

Здравствуйте, решили не много "извратиться" и выполнить задачу по наполнению сайта таким способом как - в excel через vba написать программу чтобы она считывала excel  и добавляла данные в форму (как-то так), суть этого заменить копипаст. 
(да это можно выполнить парсером на php, но суть сделать именно этим способом)

Возникла проблема с полем name - description
Фрагмент кода HTML страницы, которую заполняет макрос

```
 <label>Заголовок</label>
 <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" value="">
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>
 <br />

        <label>Описание - Meta</label>
 <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Описание" value="">
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>
 <br />

        <label>Ключевые слова - Meta</label>
 <input type="text" name="key_words" placeholder="Ключевые слова" value="">
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>
 <br />

        <label>url</label>
 <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="#" value="#">
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>
 <br />

        <label>Короткое описание</label>
 <div style="width:100%;height:200px;">
 <textarea name="prev" placeholder="Короткое описание раздела" style="width:100%;height:180px;"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>

 <label>Полное описание</label>
 <div style="width:100%;height:600px;">
 <textarea name="text" id="ckedit" placeholder="Полное описание раздела"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div style="color:#FF0000;"></div>
 <br />
```

Это Макрос в Excel

```
 Sub КнопкаНовыйФотоаппарат_Щелчок()
    Dim IE As Object
    x = Sheets("Переменные").Range("ТекущаяСтрока") ' номер строки
    y = "Получилось"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://shema-servis.ru/admin/add_dir/1787"
    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.document.all("title").Value = ("Получилось")    ' Заголовок
    IE.document.all("key_words").Value = ("Получилось")   ' Ключевые слова - Meta
    IE.document.all("prev").Value = ("Получилось")    ' Короткое описание
    IE.document.all("description").Value = ("Не получается") ' !!!ЭТА СТРОЧКА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!!
```

End Sub
Почему форму с именем "description", макрос не заполняет? Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: а пробовали менять название description например на dscptn ?
Я никогда с VBA не работал вплотную, но из опыта могу посоветовать избегать названий которые хоть по малой вероятности, но могут быть служебными зарезервированными в системе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на странице скорее всего есть еще один элемент, в частности:

```
<meta name="description"....
```

и в таком случае

```
document.all('description')
```

вернет коллекцию из по крайней мере двух элементов. вам нужно пользоваться более точным методом определения элементов, которые вы хотите заполнить. возможно хватит индекса `document.all('description')[1].value`, возможно циклом придется пройтись по этой коллекции и узнать тип элемента или еще какие-то признаки проверить.
на javascript'е так:

```
var descs = document.all('description');
for(var i=0; i<descs.length; i++){
  if(descs[i].nodeName =='INPUT'){
    descs[i].value="Получилось";
  }
}
```